# git: all local branches are behind the remote. How can I bring them all up to the remote state?

Tags: git, branch

I've cloned a remote repository which has several branches, worked on one of those branches, committed the changes and pushed. 
After a time interval during which colleagues have modified the remote repository further (and during which I've possibly forgotten how to use git), I need to make more changes.  I don't need to keep any local changes.
First I try to bring my local repo up to date by doing

```
git fetch --all
```

then I try to switch to the required branch by

```
git checkout -f branchname
```

but git says

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/branchname' by 85 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

So I take that to mean that my local branch is stuck somewhere behind the commit corresponding to the equivalent remote branch, despite doing a fetch that I hoped would make my repo equal to the remote one. What's the clearest and most straightforward way to do this? I could start with a new clone, but that seems a bit crude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to run :

`git merge origin/branchname`

Why ?

With `git fetch --all`, you've already retrieve all commits made by your colleagues. You just have to integrate them into your local branch. Since it says that your branch can be fast-forwarded, you simply have to run `git merge origin/branchname`.

Remainder : even if `branchname` and `origin/branchname` are linked together (we say that `branchname` tracks `origin/branchname`), they are not the same. So your have to merge (or rebase) `origin/branchname` on `branchname` to have all commits in `origin/branchname` appears in `branchname`

Answer (score 4):

After `git checkout -f branchname`, do `git pull origin branchname`

Answer (score 1):

I use [git up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up) for this. Apart from updating all your local branches, it will also stage and unstage any local changes you have. Saved me quite a few key strokes since I've been using it.

Comment: git up? That's a non-standard feature, right? Actually I want to discard any local changes and return to the exact state of the remote repo.